# Find the index of pixels in an image statisfies one condition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an image include 4 values {3,-3,1,-1} as figure
[image]

Let call the index of pixel that its values equals 1 or -1 pixel in contour. These pixels will create a contour that surrounds the yellow color (-3). Now, I want to find all index pixels in the contour and plus padding position inward and outward contour. As the red color, padding is set 1, hence, the index of these pixels include pixel in the contour {1,-1} and padding index as the red color. In that task, I want to find all pixel indices. How to implement that idea in matlab code. This is my code to find the index in the contour

```
%% Let define the image I
idx=find(I==1|I==-1);
padding=1;
%%Continue
```

Update: My expected result as the above figure in white region. Hence, the indices are such as 13,14,15,..21,24,...

**UPDATE**

Firstly, thank Andrew and Rayryeng for your answer. I would like to extedn my problem. As the above description, the contour is created by {1,-1}. Now, I want to ignore 1 and -1, so the image I only has {3,-3}. And I defined the contour is pixel in the edge of {3,-3} such as figure. Keep the same idea of padding and pixel index. How to find the indices of pixels in contour and near contour (call narrow band of contour)(expected result is white color)
[image]

Comment: I'm having a very hard time following your problem description.  Can you highlight what pixel locations in the above figure would be sent to the output?  Can you show us more examples?  I've probably read your problem description at least 5 times, and I still don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @rayryeng: sorry my English is so bad. let see my update

Comment: should row 11 be green? or white?

Comment: Sorry. I am mistaken. I update it. BTW, I found a solution that is used canny edge detection but it takes long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too difficult you are on the right track. If you have the **image processing toolbox**, I recommend taking a look at [morphological operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-filtering.html). Specifically you want to use [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) my code has all the details you need.

```
%rather than using find, we create a binary mask. Its not the indicies of
%the matching elements as find gives. its is 1/true if the value matches the
%criteria, and 0/false otherwise.
mask = (im=1 | im=-1);

%create a 3x3 rectangle structuring element. We use a 3x3 because we want
%to expand the image by one pixel. basically the structring element (Strel)
%is our kernal, if you know image processing this is the same thing. 
%a = [0 0 0 0;
%     0 1 1 1;
%     0 1 1 1;
%     0 1 1 1];
%our kernal is center at 2,2 (for this example) which are these elements
%     0 0 0  of a  think a(1:3,1:3) now what the dialate operation
%     0 1 1  says is, if the majority of these pixels are ones... they
%     0 1 1  should probabaly all be ones so all those 0s will become ones
%the size of the kernal 3x3 ensures we are only growing our image one
%pixel, hope that makes sense    
se = strel('square',3);

%now we dilate, or 'expand' our mask with our structuring element
expanded_mask = imdilate(mask,se);

%if you still want the indicies you can use find on our expanded mask
idx = find(expanded_mask==1);
```

**EDIT: without morphological operations/image processing toolbox**
This method uses lots of for loops, so it isn't the fastest, and doens't do error checking, but it will work. My dilate function says if the majority of the pixels are ones make them all ones.

```
function expanded_mask=DilateBinaryImage(bin_im, kernal_size)
    [max_row,max_col] = size(bin_im);

    %since we are opening the mask (only adding 1s), we can start off with the
    %same values of the mask, and simply add extra 1's as needed
    expanded_mask = bin_im;

    %we don't want to go off the edge of our image with this kernal
    %so we offset it a bit
    kern_padding = floor(kernal_size/2);

    %this ignores the edges
    for (curr_row=kern_padding+1:1:max_row - kern_padding)
       for (curr_col=kern_padding+1:1:max_col - kern_padding)
          %we do 2 sums, one for rows, one for columns
          num_ones = sum(sum(bin_im(curr_row-kern_padding:curr_row+kern_padding,curr_col-kern_padding:curr_col+kern_padding)));

          %if the majority of vlaues are 1, we use floor to help with corner
          %cases
          if (num_ones >= floor((kernal_size*kernal_size)/2))
              %make all the values one
              expanded_mask(curr_row-kern_padding:curr_row+kern_padding,curr_col-kern_padding:curr_col+kern_padding) = 1;
          end
       end
    end


end
```

and then called it like this

```
kernal_size= 3;
mask = (I==1 | I==-1);
expanded_mask = DilateBinaryImage(mask, kernal_size);
idx = find(expanded_mask==1);
```

my dilate function doesn't work at the edges of the binary image. it just copies them exactly.

Comment: very pefect. It is one kind of algorithm that I read before. After read your implementation, I remembered it. How about other way to find it without the morphological operation. Could you suggest to me by mathematic?

Comment: @user8430 - Morphological dilation is equivalent to a maximum filter.  Look at local pixel neighbourhoods and the output is the maximum value within the neighbourhood.  If you remember what we talked about earlier with `im2col`, you can deconstruct pixel neighbourhoods into columns, take the max of each column, then use `col2im` to reconstruct the output back into an image.

Comment: It is one good idea. The idea based on the a window and it will run with its center is pixel in contour. For each pixel in contour, we find these maximum index (3) and minimum index(-3) (I think). And these index will be construct a narrow region. Is it right?

Comment: ThPs method works great if you don't have the image processing toolbox. I added a new solution that doesn't use the toolbox but still mimics the dilate function. It isn't robust and may not work in every case, but it was just a quick solution

Comment: Thank you. Could you look at the my update question?

Comment: if row 11 should be geen. then you simply do the dilation twice. `kernal_size=3;mask = (I==-3); expand1 = DilateBinaryImage(mask, kernal_size); expand2 = DilateBinaryImage(expand1, kernal_size);idx=find(expand2_mask==1);` or in the first example`expand1 = imdilate(mask,se); expand2 = imdilate(expand1,se);`

Comment: @Andrew: sorry, the update question has new input image that only has {3,-3}. It is different with case A that has {3,-3,1,-1}. So how to find the mask variance

Comment: the statement `mask = (I==1 | I==-1)` is very similar to your `find(I==1 | I==-1)` the value in the parenthesis is the same. So just think, if I wanted to do `find(I==-3)` then that means the new method is `mask=(I==-3)`

Comment: @andrew If i use mask=(I=3) then it returns all pixel index inside the region that indicates by yellow color. Hence, it does not similar my expected. At the first step we must find the mask and then apply morphological to expand the contour. However, the finding mask becomes difficult if image only has 3and-3. Let defined the mask region is created by pixels in boundary between 3and -3 as figure. I used canny edge detection to find mask, but it takes long time. It think we have other simple way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70430/discussion-between-andrew-and-user8430).

Comment: You should probably ask a different question instead of editing this one. Your requirements are now very different from your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your image is N-by-M pixles. In MATLAB arrays are stored in column order (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html for more information). You can use `I` in column format as follows. First you contour pixels are given by

```
idx=find(I(:)==1|I(:)==-1);
```

Now, if you wish to pad downward and upward it is quite simple:

```
idx_up=idx - padding;
idx_up = idx_up(idx_up>0);
idx_down=idx + padding;
idx_down = idx_down(idx_down<=N*M);
```

Note that `idx_up` and `idx_down` will also contain contour pixels.
Similarly you can pad to the left\right:

```
idx_left=idx - padding*N;
idx_left = idx_left(idx_left>0);
idx_right=idx + padding*N;
idx_right = idx_right(idx_right<=N*M);
```

And combine the overall pixels:

```
PaddedContour = false(N,M);
PaddedContour(unique([idx;idx_up;idx_down;idx_left;idx_right])) = true;
```